# Como selecionar registros em uma tabela usando como referência a datetime presente?

Tags: php, mysql

Esse select me retorna os registros mais antigos aos futuros. Mas queria excluir dos resultados os eventos que já passaram e exibir em primeiro lugar o evento atual.

```
SELECT id, programa, descricao,data_hora 
   from wp_programacao
   where id >= (SELECT programa
                 from  wp_programacao
                 where data_hora <= now()
                 order by data_hora desc
                 limit 1)
  order by data_hora asc
  limit 5;
```

Comment: experimente trocar `where data_hora <= now()` por `where data_hora < now()`

Comment: e por que deixar como citação, não foi vc que escreveu?

Comment: Sim... Vou retirar

Comment: @LucasCosta  Continua me retornando o registro mais antigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, programa, descricao, data_hora 
from wp_programacao
where data_hora >= now() 
order by data_hora asc
limit 5;
```